# mysqli_real_escape_string using environment

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using mysqli extension in php for connection to database. I've such a simple question. Is it better to use mysqli instead of mysql and why is it necessary to use mysqli_real_escape_string ? what is this function doing exactly ? Thanks ...

Comment: Side note: please consider using PDO. It's as powerful as MySQLi (if not better), it's easier to learn and it can be used with other DBMS engines apart from MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put a little example not using SQL. Imagine you have this PHP code:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, world!';
```

Now you want to replace `world` with `O'Hara`:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, O'Hara!'; // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

Yeah, of course, that is not valid PHP. You need to escape the single quote since it's interpreted as a literal quote rather than the string delimiter:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, O\'Hara!';
```

You have exactly the same problem when composing SQL queries. If you inject random input into your code, sooner or later it'll break. You need to *encode* input so it's handled as literal input rather than broken code.

How can you do that? Well, MySQL accepts `\'` just like PHP (though it's only a coincidence: other database engines use other escape methods). So the dumbest solution is to add back slashes here and here:

```
SELECT id FROM user WHERE name='O\'Hara';
```

Of course, it's a lot of work to hard-code all the possible characters that need escaping (and you'll probably forget some of them) so you can use a function that does the job for you: either `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

The question is: is this good enough? Well, it kind of works, but it leads to annoying code that's difficult to maintain:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "' WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "'";
```

... and you still need to take care of surrounding the complete value with single quotes... which are not always mandatory (think of numbers)... What a mess. Can't someone invent something better? Good news is: they did! It's called **prepared statements**:

```
// Just an example, I invented the syntax
$sql = 'UPDATE user SET name=:name WHERE id=:id';
$params = array(
    'name' => "O'Brian",
    'id' => 31416,
);
$MyDbConnection->execute($sql, $params);
```

In real life:

- MySQLi has the `prepare()` method to accomplish this. [Find some examples there](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
- Legacy MySQL extension... has nothing: it does not support prepared statements at all! If you use this extension, you are stuck with the annoying add-quotes-yourself and string concatenation methods.

I hope this explains the whole question.

Comment: So if i am using mysqli_prepare() function it isn't necessary to use mysqli_real_escape_string yes ?

Comment: Not only it's not necessary: if you use both, you'll end up with real bogus "\" symbols inserted into the database, just as typing `echo 'Hello, O\\\'Hara!';`

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is slightly faster than Mysqli, but it would have no effect in 99% of web development. The real advantage is that Mysqli is more focused around classes and methods.

Mysqli_real_escape_string is a precautionary function to escape any illegal/malicious characters in a string that you are going to use in a Mysql query. There is also a standard mysql_real_escape_string function aswell. If in doubt it is better to use it than not use it, but beware too many may cause speed issues with your scripts/queries.

To cut it short, if you're writing procedural PHP use standard Mysql, but if you're writing object orientated code then use Mysqli and maximise it's potential. You must always make your queries safe, mysql_real_escape_string is just one way.

Hope this helps!